# How to send Django model object's details as answer according to the user's choice of InlineKeyboardButton?

Tags: python-3.x, django, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm new to creating telegram bots with Django. I selected **python-telegram-bot** library for creating bots with Django.

I've created a Django model, named as **category**:

```
class category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category_id = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and **product**:

```
class product(models.Model):
    product_category = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    cost = models.FloatField()
    img = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Successfully created InlineKeyboardButtons and placed id of each product model object to each button, with these functions:

```
def product(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query.data

    product_button_list = []
    
    for each in product.objects.select_related().filter(product_category_id = query):
        product_button_list.append(InlineKeyboardButton(each.name, callback_data=each.id))
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_menu(product_button_list,n_cols=2))
    update.callback_query.message.edit_text("Mahsulotni tanlang!", reply_markup=reply_markup)

def build_menu(buttons,n_cols,header_buttons=None,footer_buttons=None):
  menu = [buttons[i:i + n_cols] for i in range(0, len(buttons), n_cols)]
  if header_buttons:
    menu.insert(0, header_buttons)
  if footer_buttons:
    menu.append(footer_buttons)
  return menu
```

When the user selects a button named as the name of the product model object, I am receiving the correct id of the product model object, tested with printing the query:

```
def product_info(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query.data
    print(query)

    obj = product.objects.filter(pk=query)
    print(obj)
```

Question: How to reply Django product model object's fields including its image to the user according to the user's chosen product?

**Like:**

*You have chosen a product:*

*Image of the product*

*Name of the product*

*Cost of the product*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, I have successed so far:

```
filename = 'path_until_media_folder' + str(obj.img.url) 

update.callback_query.bot.send_photo(update.effective_chat.id, photo=open(filename, 'rb'))
```